# Processing org-mode files in python

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

I have lots of documentation in emacs org-mode files. I would like to process some of those files from my python programs. One useful example would be to import org tables into python dictionaries or lists, or to look for a specific section in an org file (marked by the `*` special characters). I think it would not be difficult to code this `org-mode-importer` in python, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel. I have found [Orgnode](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/orgnode.html), but it seems this is not actively maintained.

Are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html

Comment: Frustrating that there is nothing that seems active and is in pypi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is PyOrgMode and NEO:

https://github.com/bjonnh/PyOrgMode

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-04/msg00598.html

Tools for parsing .org files are generally listed here:
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html